# Create multiple agents with Java JADE

Tags: java, eclipse, agents-jade, agents

I am kind of new with JADE platform in eclipse. I want to create multiple agents, I have put a for loop and incremented the counter to create the agents, It used to work well but when I added the ThiefAgent, it didn't work. It only creates one PoliceAgent and one ThiefAgent.
The code works perfectly but it does not create many agents.

this is the main.java code:

```
 public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*********************************************************************/
    Runtime rt=Runtime.instance();
    ProfileImpl p=new ProfileImpl();
    p.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, "localhost");
    p.setParameter(Profile.GUI, "true");


    ContainerController cc1=rt.createMainContainer(p);


    /**************creation of 5 police agents*****************/

    for(int i=1; i<6; i++)
    {

       AgentController ac1;
    try {



        ac1=cc1.createNewAgent("PoliceAgent"+i, "Agents.PoliceAgent", null);


        ac1.start();    

    } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }



         /**************creation of 3 thief agents*****************/

        for(int j=1; j<4; j++)
        {

       AgentController ac2;
    try {


        ac2=cc1.createNewAgent("ThiefAgent"+j, "Agents.ThiefAgent",    null);


        ac2.start();    

    } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }

        }
      }
```

I tried to put one For loop for both agents but nothing changed. 
What's the mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create PoliceAgent class:

   ```
   public class PoliceAgent extends Agent{
       @Override
       public void setup()
       {
           System.out.println("Police agent name is: " +getAID().getName());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create ThiefAgent class:

   ```
   public class ThiefAgent extends Agent{
       @Override
       public void setup()
       {
           System.out.println("Thief agent name is: " +getAID().getName());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create AgentWorker main class:

   ```
   public class PoliceAgent{

      public static void main(String... args){
          Runtime runtime = Runtime.instance();
          Profile profile = new ProfileImpl();
          profile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, "localhost");
          profile.setParameter(Profile.GUI, "true");
          ContainerController containerController = runtime.createMainContainer(profile);

          for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
              AgentController policeAgentController;
              try {
                  policeAgentController = containerController.createNewAgent("PoliceAgent"+i, "ua.agent.PoliceAgent", null);
                  policeAgentController.start();    
              } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

          for(int i=1; i<4; i++){
              AgentController thiefAgentController;
              try {
                  thiefAgentController = containerController.createNewAgent("ThiefAgent"+i, "ua.agent.ThiefAgent", null);
                  thiefAgentController.start();    
              } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
      }

   }
   ```

I don't see mistakes in this code, but i write 3 classes an they work. Since I don't see the whole picture, so I can only say that the problem could be in the class of agents and the problem of Jade.